# Is my question about continuous delivery for tvOS applications off-topic?

Tags: discussion, questions

I'm starting development on a tvOS application and want to learn more about what continuous delivery options exist for tvOS.  Unlike iOS, tvOS does not support enterprise distribution, so I cannot use my existing workflow.

My question would ask:

- What continuous delivery options exist for tvOS applications?  What infrastructure is required to support ad-hoc or enterprise delivery?
- Apple provides TestFlight distribution for testing tvOS applications, which is the workflow for submitting to the App Store (the test build becomes the App Store build).  Is this my only build delivery option?

I want to contribute quality questions to this site, but fear that I'm asking for something too specific that might attract SaaS recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

> What continuous delivery options exist for tvOS applications?

Not sure about tvOS applications. But, you can structure your question with all the options you have explored and ask about any more which you might have missed. This would help the answerers to answer better, rather than simply listing out a list of services available.

You can then follow-up with subsequent questions on the answers received.

> Apple provides TestFlight distribution for testing tvOS applications, which is the workflow for submitting to the App Store (the test build becomes the App Store build). Is this my only build delivery option?

Yeah. This is well on-topic here.

> I want to contribute quality questions to this site, but fear that I'm asking for something too specific that might attract SaaS recommendations.

Welcome to the site, and we really appreciate you wanting to contribute high quality posts to the site. And I can assure you that this site's community is one of the friendliest ones, and will help you improve the quality of your posts, and make sure you get high quality answers too :)